# Liapunov and probaility convergence proof

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, asymptotics

Let $X_j$, $j=1,2,\ldots,X_n$ be independent and take on values $\pm j$ with probability $1/2$ each.  Use theorem $2.7.1$ to show that $$\sqrt{\frac3{n}}\bar{X}\xrightarrow{L}N(0,1).$$

> **Theorem 2.7.1 Liapunov.**  *Let $X_i$ ($i=1,\ldots,n$) be independently distributed with means $E(X_i)=\xi_i$ and variances $\sigma_i^2$, and with finite third moments.  If 
>   $$Y_n=\frac{\bar{X}-E(\bar{X})}{\sqrt{\operatorname{Var}(\bar{X})}}=\frac{\sqrt{n}\ (\bar{X}-\bar{\xi})}{\sqrt{(\sigma_1^2+\cdots+\sigma_n^2)/n}},$$
>   then
>   $$Y_n\xrightarrow{L}N(0,1),$$
>   provided
>   $$\bigg[E\bigg(\sum|X_i-\xi_i|^3\bigg)\bigg]^2=o\bigg[\bigg(\sum\sigma_i^2\bigg)^3\bigg].$$*

I am kind of confused as too approach this proof using Theorem 2.7.1. Any help to get me started would be helpful

Comment: Simply compute $E(\overline X)$ and $Var(\overline X)$. You know what $\overline X$ is?

Comment: I am confused on ho to do it

Comment: $$\mathbb E[\bar X_n] = \mathbb E\left[\frac1n\sum_{j=1}^n X_j\right] = \frac1n\sum_{j=1}^n\mathbb E[X_j] = 0$$ and
$$
\mathrm{Var}(\bar X_n) = \mathrm{Var}\left(\frac1n\sum_{j=1}^n X_j\right) = \frac1{n^2}\sum_{j=1}^n \mathrm{Var}(X_j)=\frac1{n^2}\sum_{j=1}^n j^2 = \frac{(n+1)(2n+1)}{6n}.$$

Comment: Don't forget to check that the sufficient condition  in the theorem is satisfied.

Comment: How do calculate the third moment given that mean and varianc e